# Open $modal from the service and pass variables to the controller

Tags: angularjs

I implement my own wrapper for `$modal.` Instead of open it in `controller` I would like to do that in `service` and then inject this service into others components

```
mainApp.factory('modalsService', ['$modal', function($modal) {
    return {
        show: function(text) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: "modals/modal-template.html",
                controller: "modalCtrl",
                resolve: function() {
                    return text
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])

mainApp.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'text',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, text) {
        alert(text)
        $scope.msg = text
        $scope.confirm = function() {
            $modalInstance.close()
        }
}])
```

My issue is in `alert(text)` -- it prints "undefined". By some reason I can not pass this text from service to the controller.

Can you help me with that please?

Comment: do you reviewed your code before putting here. Mistake is clearly visible.

Comment: is this your real code ?? there are glaring mistakes in the code...

Comment: Looks like you lost some parts of your code when you were copying it to the questions. `['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'text', `.

Comment: What do you mean? It is what I have now

Comment: I fixed the broken copy-paste typos, so it won't distract from real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix `resolve` part of the service:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: "modals/modal-template.html",
    controller: "modalCtrl",
    resolve: {
        text: function() {
            return text;
        }
    }
});
```

Note how you explicitly tell that you want controller to be injected with `text`.

Then you simple use it in any controller like this:

```
modalsService.show('This is a text');
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FSMV0AvSykrpemqwTNB9?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for making this clear. Actually my issue also was in temaplte? I add the controller to it, and now it works

Comment: Good, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like:

```
mainApp.controller('Ctrl',
    function ($scope,modalsService ) {

        var text = 'your message'
        $scope.openModel = function() {
            modalsService.show(text)
        }
});
```

And,change modalCtrl as,

```
mainApp.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope','$modalInstance','text',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, text) {
        alert(text)
        $scope.msg = text
        $scope.confirm = function() {
            $modalInstance.close()
        }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to pass my text not as a predefined var but as a variable from a component where my service has been injected

Comment: Its ok.. You should follow this approach.. And as @dfsQ answer change,   resolve: {
        text: function() {
            return text;
        }
    }

Comment: Can we avoid useing the first controller? What I am trying to achieve is to have less coupled component which is responsible for showing modal dialogs and can be easily injected to others without additional dependencies. This first ctrl broke this idea

Comment: No, you need this. As you need to inject a service inside controller, to call its method.

Comment: I mean to call services methods, you need to inject your service inside controller. so from your controller you will call your service and pass the text.